# list of lists creation

Tags: python

in my python code i want to create a list of lists...in a loop ...
but after completion of the loop i end up with the same list in all elements...is it because the lists are pointed to and not stored ? If so, how can i come up with a solution to my problem ?
Following is my code

```
    list_lists=list()
    list_temp=list()
    for i in xrange(n):
        ind_count =0
        del list_temp[0:len(list_temp)]
        for j in xrange(no_words):
            if inp[i] == words[j]:
                list_temp.append(j)
        list_lists.append(list_temp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of deleting the items of your list (`del list_temp[0:len(list_temp)]`) just assign a new list: `list_temp = list()`. You can also use the shorthand: `list_temp = []`

The problem that you are facing is that you are always reusing the same list you created in the second line: `list_temp = list()`. You are just inserting references to this one list over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is the same as what you do:

```
n = 10
b = []
for x in range(n):
... b.append([])
b
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

(So b is a list of n lists)

The following seems to be/do the same:

```
a = [[]]*n
a
[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

(a is also a list of n lists)

```
a == b
True

b[0].append(4)
b
[[4], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

(Makes sense)

However:

```
a[0].append(4)
a
[[4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4], [4]]
```